# What does a "run on a bank" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, finance

I've heard it in several finance movies and the sentiment is kind of clear but what does it actually mean, "a run on a bank"?

Comment: I typed your phrase exactly as it was, i.e., ***"a run on a bank"***, into Google. Here are the results. They explain the phrase in great detail. --->  https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=+%22a+run+on+a+bank%22%3F

Comment: Note, "kinda" is not an accepted abbreviation in written English. It is only used in song lyrics, quoted dialog, and very informal writing such as tweets. You should use "kind of" ;-)

Comment: If you prefer to do your research using movies, watch *It's a Wonderful Life*.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK, regarding "kinda": seems like it's only an opinion, it is surely informal, but unless u define written English as something more than essay/novel/etc writing I'm 100% correct. Regarding google: somehow I didn't get that result, but I'm also not using eng lang google.

Comment: It's not 'only an opinion.' If you don't believe me then you might like to submit a separate question about it. Note that such abbreviations are quite commonly and mistakenly used by many non-native English speakers. As I say, you may see it on social media but with even moderately formal writing, such as you'll see on an English language website, it's not acceptable.   Analyse this ----> https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kind+of%2Ckinda&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckind%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckinda%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means a large number of customers trying to withdraw their deposits in a short period of time. The bank only holds enough cash to allow a small percentage of all deposits to be withdrawn. So if the run is big enough, the bank's cash is exhausted and they have to close, at least for a short time.

Comment: Good answer. The technical term for the system that allows banks to do this is _fractional-reserve banking_.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't heard that term. There are also set percentages of deposits that banks must hold with the reserve banks, called _statutory reserve deposits_ .